# jquery tabs sometimes not rendered

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have a strange problem in a web-app (using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3: the tabs (of the Tabs-plugin) are SOMETIMES rendered correctly and SOMETIMES not. "incorrect" means that the `div`s with the tab-contents are shown one below the other, no

That happens with IE7,8,10 and FF26 and on machines with rigid policies as well as those with more relaxed policy.
The browser may show a page incorrectly and then you just press F5 and the reload renders correctly.
Has anyone else had similar problems before? I have no idea how to approach this thing, yet the project-mgr wants to see something happening...

(I have validated the HTML/JS using CSE HTMLValidator and it did not report issues, also the JS console does not show any errors, but reports a few warnings (like 'Expected declaration, but found '*' for CSS-declaration like '`*cursor: hand;`' etc., but nothing related to the stuff I do)

Comment: Can you show the problem on a fiddle?

Comment: I thought about a slimmed-down example, but it's not that easy - because anything that I'd slim-down could be somehow related to the problem - so the question is more about a "debugging-procedure", things to look at etc. rather than an issue of fixing a buggy line of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you loading the tab content? Is it in the page when it's downloaded, or are they loaded via Ajax?

If already present in the document, you should try hiding (display: none) the content div's - that way you won't see them all if the tab initialization fails (which is likely what is happening intermittently).

This sounds like it could be a timing issue - where are the tabs initialized? Make sure you have them in the document.ready function so you are sure jQuery and jQuery UI are fully loaded first.

After a failure you could try manually initializing the tabs from the console - the result (success or failure) should give some additional insight.

Also use Firebug to examine the content divs to see if they are getting changed by the tab initialization - there should be classes added.

Comment: Thanks John, for these helpful suggestions. First of all, all content is in the page. Initialization is in $(document).ready. Trying to call the init from the console gave no msgs at all (but returned an object containing all divs) - but also did not change the UI.

Comment: And regarding classes being added: the container-div has "ui-tabs ui-widget" etc. added, the divs for the individual tabs are not being changed.

Comment: When clicking on the tabs in that state, the console shows `Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier`. That (like several errors when checking the HTML in Firefoxes "Inspect element" (or is it "Examine" - I'm using german) seems to suggest that the HTML is buggy - but HTML Validator has not found issues with mismatching tags...

Comment: That error usually happens if you have the content DIVs messed up, so that it can't find the ID's specified in the <LI>s. Check that you have the DIVs inside the same DIV that contains the UL. Also make sure you don't have a '#' at the start of the DIV ID's (you need it in the href in the LI, but not in the matching DIVs ID).

Comment: Well...surprise, surprise...on re-examining the HTML, I found a missing div, checked my PHP and fixed the error - and finally everything renders nicely! I'm sure the HTML was complete before, but the whole thing has changed so much in the last few days that I can not exactly reproduce - and anyway, I'm glad it works :)  Thanks again for your support and useful suggestions!